# Change mode for plotly.express

Tags: python, plotly

I have a bunch of plotly plots. I am giving example from the plotly site.

I want to plot all of them in dark mode.
I have to manually enter `template="plotly_dark"` for each plot.

How can I change the default setting of my display so that I do not have to manually enter `template="plotly_dark"` for each plot?

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species", marginal_y="violin",
           marginal_x="box", trendline="ols", template="plotly_dark")
fig.show()
```

---

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
df["e"] = df["sepal_width"]/100
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species", error_x="e", error_y="e", template="plotly_dark")
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it as default as below

```
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.express as px

pio.templates.default = "plotly_dark"

df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species", marginal_y="violin",
           marginal_x="box", trendline="ols")
fig.write_image('im1.png')

df["e"] = df["sepal_width"]/100
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species", error_x="e", error_y="e")
fig.write_image('im2.png')
```

Ref: https://plotly.com/python/templates/